# Migrating from .live() to .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a small code, that responsible for drawing newly added comments. THe problem is, when i  rewrote code to use `on` instead of removed `live`, my code doesnt work on new elements, that were added after page load

Here is my code

```
$(function(){
    $('.show-comment-form').on("click", (function(){
        dataattr = $(this).data('comment');
        $('#new_comment').remove();
        $('.message-'+dataattr).append(partial_form);
        $("#comment_parent_id").val(dataattr);
        return false;
    }))
})
```

HTML

```
<a href="/phrases/52/create_comment?parent_id=16" class="show-comment-form" data-comment="16">Reply</a>
```

How do i add click event to all future elements, that will be added after page load?

Comment: [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is pretty well documented.

Comment: You should really read jquery API documentation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
$('.show-comment-form').on("click", (function(){
```

to:

```
$(document).on("click", '.show-comment-form', (function(){
```

When adding elements dynamically, to use on you target an element that exists on the page already, in this example `document`, then you pass the element you want to attach the listener to as a parameter to `.on()`.

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

Also note that you want to target an element as close to the dynamically inserted elements as possible:

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document
>   tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must
>   compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every
>   element in the path from the event target up to the top of the
>   document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document
>   location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive
>   use of `document` or `document.body` for delegated events on large
>   documents.

Comment: Using the `document` for the context isn't a smart move.

Comment: @psycketom That's the best that can be used with this example - no other HTML is given. At the same time, I agree, and that should be included in the answer

Comment: @psycketom - As Ian said, `document` is a worst case example. It's always better to target an element closer to the actual element you will be binding to.